# I'm getting some weird errors when I compile this

Tags: c, compiler-errors

this is my first time using stackoverflow so I hope I'm doing this right. I'm having some trouble with 1 program from one of my classes, I've already finished the other two. This one is problem 3, if you [go to this pdf](http://ece15.ucsd.edu/Labs/lab3.pdf) and scroll down for problem 3, there will be the information I'm using to complete this program (but it is terribly written I must say.) Anyway, I'm getting these really weird errors when I compile, does anyone have any reason why my code won't compile/won't work? The point of the program is to read in a sample dna input and compare it with 2 others. I've made a sample file just like it says [in the instructions](http://ece15.ucsd.edu/Labs/lab3.pdf) . Thank you for your time!

what errors i am getting:

```
     dna.c: In function ‘main’:
dna.c:12: error: expected ‘]’ before ‘;’ token
dna.c:13: error: expected ‘]’ before ‘;’ token
dna.c:14: error: expected ‘]’ before ‘;’ token
dna.c:15: error: expected ‘]’ before ‘;’ token
dna.c:21: error: ‘first’ undeclared (first use in this function)
dna.c:21: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
dna.c:21: error: for each function it appears in.)
dna.c:22: error: ‘second’ undeclared (first use in this function)   
dna.c:23: error: ‘third’ undeclared (first use in this function)
dna.c:25: error: ‘last’ undeclared (first use in this function)
dna.c: In function ‘read_DNA’:
dna.c:43: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
dna.c:43: error: too few arguments to function ‘fgets’
dna.c:45: error: expected expression before ‘;’ token
dna.c: In function ‘print_DNA’:
dna.c:76: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
```

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_IN_LENGTH 241;
#define OUT_LENGTH 60;
FILE *input;
FILE *output;
int read_DNA(char sequence[]);
double compare_DNA(char seq1[], char seq2[], char seq3[], int n);
void print_DNA(char seq1[], char seq2[], char seq3[], int n);

int main()
{
  char first[MAX_IN_LENGTH];
  char second[MAX_IN_LENGTH];
  char third[MAX_IN_LENGTH];
  int last[MAX_IN_LENGTH];
  int i;
  int length;
  double percent;
  input = fopen("dna_input.dat", "r");
  output = fopen("dna_output.dat", "w");
  length =read_DNA(first);
  length =read_DNA(second);
  length =read_DNA(third);
  fprintf(output,"Comparison between sequence # 1 and sequence #2:\n");
  percent=compare_DNA(first, second, last,length);
  print_DNA(first, second, last, length);
  fprintf(output,"The overlap percentage is %.1f%%\n",percent*100);
  fprintf(output,"Comparison between sequence # 1 and sequence #3:\n");
  print_DNA(first, third, last,length);
  fprintf(output,"The overlap percentage is %.1f%%\n",percent*100);
  fprintf(output,"Comparison between sequence # 2 and sequence #3:\n");
  percent=compare_DNA(second,third,last,length);
  print_DNA(second, third, last, length);
  fprintf(output,"The overlap percentage is %.1f%%\n",percent*100);
  fclose(input);
  fclose(output);
  return 0;
}


int read_DNA(char sequence[])
{
  fgets(sequence, MAX_IN_LENGTH, input);
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<MAX_IN_LENGTH; i++)
  {
    if(sequence[i]=='\0')
      return i;

  }
  return MAX_IN_LENGTH;
}

double compare_DNA(char seq1[], char seq2[], char seq3[], int n)
{
  int i,count=0;
  for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
  {  
    if(seq1[i]==seq2[i])
    {
      seq3[i]=seq1[i];
       count++;
    }
    else
      seq3[i]=' ';
  }
  return (double)count/(n-1);
}


void print_DNA(char seq1[], char seq2[], char seq3[], int n)
{
  int i=0;
  int lines, j, start, stop;
  lines =n/OUT_LENGTH;
  if( n%OUT_LENGTH!=0)
    lines++;
  for(j=0;j<lines;j++)
  {
    start=j*OUT_LENGTH;
    stop=(j+1)*OUT_LENGTH;
    if(stop>=n)
      stop=n-1;
    for(i=start;i<stop;i++)
      fprintf(output,"%c",seq1[i]);
    fprintf(output,"\n");
    for(i=start;i<stop;i++)    
    {
      fprintf(output,"%c",seq3[i]);
      if(seq3[i]==' ')
        fprintf(output,"");
    }
    fprintf(output,"\n");   
    for(i=start;i<stop;i++)   
    {
      fprintf(output,"%c",seq2[i]);}
    fprintf(output,"\n");
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `#define` is  a ***preprocessor directive*** and it works like this

`#define foo bar` replaces all occurrences of `foo` with `bar` Provided that the `foo` doesn't come in quotes (like `"foo"` in functions like `printf` are not replaced). And a ***newline*** character separates two preprocessor directives,  and **NOT** a semicolon.

So naturally your semicolon is also substituted, So, your array declaration now becomes

`char first [241;];` Since the compiler sees the semicolon first it assumes that you have made an error by not closing the square brackets.

This error does not declare your `first, second, third` variables and thus the errors follow.

Same is the case with `OUT_LENGTH`

Comment: Cool thank you! Now I'm just getting one type of error, but it's the same error

Comment: dna.c: In function ‘main’:
dna.c:25: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘compare_DNA’ from incompatible pointer type
dna.c:26: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘print_DNA’ from incompatible pointer type
dna.c:29: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘print_DNA’ from incompatible pointer type
dna.c:32: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘compare_DNA’ from incompatible pointer type
dna.c:33: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘print_DNA’ from incompatible pointer type
Like-a-boss-5:assignment03 abbas$

Comment: The third argument in `print_DNA` and `compare_dna` is of type `char` and you are passing an `int` argument!!

Also `fgets` is incorrectly called. you need a file pointer there (After you open a file)

Answer (score 2):

Don't put semicolons in your `#define` statements.